# Failed to query daabaseNo database selected

Tags: php, mysql

i am getting error no database is selected can anybody correct the code. 
I am trying to learn php and mysql. So i tried making a database using 
 
  phpmyadmin and connect it with my php. Here is a simple example where I try to see if the database is working.

```
    <?php
    //Get values passe from form in donateform.html.
        $link;
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        $Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Donating =isset($_POST['Donating']);
        $Address = isset($_POST['Address']);
    //To prevent mysql injection
        $Name = stripcslashes($Name);
        $Mobile = stripcslashes($Mobile);
        $Email = stripcslashes($Email);
        $Donating = stripcslashes($Donating);
        $Address = stripcslashes($Address);

    //connect to the server and select  database.
        $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "gooddeeds", "");
        mysqli_select_db($link,"donaters");

        $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Name);
        $Mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Mobile);
        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Email);
        $Donating = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Donating);
        $Address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Address);

//Query the database for user
$result =mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO donaters (Name, Mobile, Email, Donating, Address) VALUES ('$Name', '$Mobile', '$Email', '$Donating', '$Address')")
    or die("Failed to query daabase".mysqli_error($link));

if(mysqli_query($result)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ".mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

and i get

```
Database query failed::: No database selected
```

which means this part of code

```
//connect to the server and select  database.
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "gooddeeds", "");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"donaters");
```

is not working (i put a different number of these ":" in each if. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following as databasename.tablename (gooddeeds.donaters)

```
INSERT INTO gooddeeds.donaters (Name, Mobile, Email, Donating, Address) VALUES ('$Name', '$Mobile', '$Email', '$Donating', '$Address')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by the first example in the php documentation. Try the the conditional to check connection.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {  
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;  
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```